# sql - Return last 3 payments for all customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with payments made by customers, I want to return the latest 3 payments for each and every user. If a new customer has only made one purchase then only show one. If a customer has made 50 purchases i want to see the last 3 payments based on date.

I am currently returning the latest payment but can't figure out how to amend this to show 3

```
Select * 
from table as tsv
left outer join 
    (select 
         p1.[Tenant Code],
         p1.[Trans Date],
         p1.[Payment Amount],
         p1.[Payment Type]
     from   
         HIS_vw_tenant_payments p1
     where  
         p1.R04_SQL_ID = (select max(p2.R04_SQL_ID)
                          from HIS_vw_tenant_payments p2
                          where p2.[Tenant Code] = p1.[Tenant Code]
                            and p2.[Account Code] = 'RENT'
                          group by [Tenant Code])
    ) as pt on tsv.[Tenant Code] = pt.[Tenant Code]
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, the `ROW_NUMBER` function is probably the way to go here:

```
SELECT [Tenant Code], [Trans Date], [Payment Amount], [Payment Type]
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Tenant Code] ORDER BY [Trans Date] DESC) rn
    FROM HIS_vw_tenant_payments
) t
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Comment: @ScottR Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI standard `row_number() function.  Something like this:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [Tenant Code] order by [Trans Date] desc) as seqnum
      from HIS_vw_tenant_payments p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 3;
```